# How to update existing info path form field value using c# in share point 2013

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013

I have a requirement like update an existing info path form field value using c# in share point 2013? Below code am trying to update. But not working. Could you please have any idea?

The below code i am using in console application.

```
SPSite site=new SPSite("site url"); 
SPWeb oWeb = site.OpenWeb(); 
SPList list = oWeb.Lists["Form Library Name"];
SPListItem ItemNewRecert = list.GetItemById(550); 
MemoryStream oMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(ItemNewRecert.File.OpenBinary()); 
XmlTextReader oReader = new XmlTextReader(oMemoryStream);

XmlDocument oDoc = new XmlDocument();


oDoc.Load(oReader);

oReader.Close();
oMemoryStream.Close();
XmlNamespaceManager nameSpaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(oDoc.NameTable);
nameSpaceManager.AddNamespace("my", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2014-03-26T22:04:35");
oDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("my:ExceptionOwnertxt", nameSpaceManager).InnerText = "Dhayanand Kalimidi";
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
SPFile oSPFile = oWeb.Folders["Exception Request"].Files.Add(ItemNewRecert.File.Name.ToString(), (encoding.GetBytes(oDoc.OuterXml)), true);
ItemNewRecert.File.Update();
```